# Would a finite number of primes imply there would be a finite number of secure exchanges on the internet?

Tags: prime-numbers, soft-question, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples, cryptography

I was teaching my class Euclid's theorem on why there are infinite number of primes. Aside from the idea of proof by contradiction, I wanted to give some more motivation as to why knowing this fact is important.

One idea is that prime numbers are the basis of modern cryptography, and a computer finds it difficult to factor a number composed of two large primes as opposed one with more than two (how much easier actually seems like an interesting problem!). The implication would be that if there are only a finite number of primes in the world, say $N$, then there are $N^2$ numbers that can be used for RSA. Even if N is very large, one could compose a running database of these factorizations and search through them to factor future messages. Therefore there would only be $N^2$ possible internet transactions, which would be a disaster for much of public infrastructure like banking and eCommerce.

References:

[https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10591/62372](http://doctrina.org/How-RSA-Works-With-Examples.html)

http://doctrina.org/How-RSA-Works-With-Examples.html

Comment: Well... there are only a finite number of primes less than $2^{4096}$... and we know all currently used RSA keys are at most that large and yet are still entirely infeasible with modern approaches and technology to crack...  Limiting things to finite amounts doesn't change our experience with numbers much when we still allow for absurdly large finite numbers to be used.

Comment: The idea of RSA is that it is impossible to try out the prime factors the given number can have in a reasonable amount of time. This could also be done if there were finite many primes , as long as factoring would be difficult enough.

Comment: I suggest looking at [Proofs from *THE BOOK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK)'s first section with several more proofs that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: A database of the prime numbers with, lets say , $300$ digits , is impossible to create since it would have far too many entries.

Comment: While I agree with the previous comments, a counterpoint would be that the infinitude of primes means that if computers somehow get much, much faster so that they can easily crack $4096$-bit codes, we can just go to a larger key, say $65536$ bits, without worrying about whether we're going to "run out of primes".

Comment: @DavidK There are more serious problems with RSA; namely that it could not be shown that the code cannot be cracked without decoding the factorization.And yes, it is possible, that a number that is secure today is not anymore secure in a few years, lets say. But if we had enough primes, we could still build up RSA (even if there were only finite many of them)

Comment: Important for RSA is that the number of primes is "dense" in the sense that the ending digits cannot be predicted and neither the beginning digits. But to answer the main question : The motivation to know that there are infinite many primes is not relevant for practical mathematics like cryptography.

Comment: The hunt of ever larger and larger primes however is motivated by the fact that we know there are infinite many, but the largest known primes are Mersenne numbers , and it is unknown whether infinite many of such primes exist, but it seems to be the case. If someone should be able to prove that finite many mersenne primes exist, we will have to look for other primes in far future, but heuristics indicate that this is not the case.

Comment: Also note that it is somehwat lucky that we know at all that there are infinite many primes. Many a bit stronger statements cannot currently be proven , as the statement that there are infinite many twin-primes.

Comment: @Peter We also believe there are only finitely many particles in the known universe, hence an upper limit on the number of bits that can be stored in one number in a computer, so we will never be able to use more than a finite number of primes in RSA. "Infinite" and "practical" don't really go together, except where "infinite" is just a shortcut to "all the numbers we'll ever need."

Comment: If there were only finitely many primes, then [I would be the Pope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), and I would excommunicate anybody who tried to spy on the Internet traffic of others, so there'd be no problem :-)

Comment: Alas I guess I have to find more convincing arguments for learning this proof. The recommendation for Proofs from the Book might be a good start!